# How to perform unit test on dropdown when click event happens

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am running unit test on angular app, When I click on dropdown, it should respond by updating front end data like id number

Frontend-template

```html
<mat-menu #menuFilter="matMenu">
   <button *ngFor="let customer of customers; let i = index" 
   (click)="onCustomerChange(i)" mat-menu-item class="selectCustomerData"> 
   {{owner.id}}</button>
 </mat-menu>
```

Backend-typescript

```js
onCustomerChange(i) {
    console.log(this.customers[i].ownerid);
    this.customerNumber = this.customers[i].ownerid;
    this.customerName = this.customers[i].ownername;
}
```

Test to be run

```js
it('should update the customer number on selecting a value from drop down',()=>{
  fixture.detectChanges();
//what should I do here
 })
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you read the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing)? StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Can you tell me how you trigger this menu? via a button click or else?

Comment: Anyways with few assumptions I've added an answer below. Check it out and enjoy!

Comment: Hi Shashank and Neo both of your answers are fulfilling ,thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first of all, a code improvement:

```
<mat-menu #menuFilter="matMenu">
   <button *ngFor="let customer of customers" 
   (click)="onCustomerChange(customer)" mat-menu-item class="selectCustomerData"> 
   {{owner.id}}</button>
 </mat-menu>
```

and in ts:

```
onCustomerChange(customerObj) {
   console.log(customerObj.ownerid);
   this.customerNumber = customerObj.ownerid;
   this.customerName = customerObj.ownername;
}
```

Now, for Unit test:

```
  it('should update the customer number on selecting a value from drop down', () => {
    component.customers = [{ ownerid: 1, ownerName: 'Person1' }, { ownerid: 2, ownerName: 'Person2' }];
    spyOn(component, 'onCustomerChange').and.callThrough();
    const e = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.selectCustomerData');
    e[1].click();
    expect(component.onCustomerChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ ownerid: 2, ownerName: 'Person2' });
    expect(component.customerNumber).toBe(2);
    expect(component.customerName).toBe('Person2');
  });
```

You can [refer to this blog to get very elaborate examples](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7)  in Angular Unit Testing.

Answer (score 1):

This has bit of work to do.

First you have to put a `id` to your buttons of your `mat-menu` to identify by the `querySelector`. Here I'm using `index` with some string concatenation. Make your own logic and follow it in the spec file. Here I've also changed `{{owner.id}}` to `{{customer.ownerid}}`, since I don't know what owner.id is refer to and It doesn't relate to the answer. Also I've added button to trigger the menu since you haven't mentioned how to do so.

```html
<mat-menu #menuFilter="matMenu">
  <button *ngFor="let customer of customers; let i = index" [id]="'btn_'+i"
          (click)="onCustomerChange(i)" mat-menu-item class="selectCustomerData">
    {{customer.ownerid}}</button>
</mat-menu>

<!-- Refer to the spec.ts how to trigger this, since I don't know your logic.-->
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menuFilter" id="btnMenu">
  Click Here to Trigger the Menu
</button>
```

Now the spec.ts

```js
let dom;
let button;
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
   // You can initialize these here, if you are planning to use it inside the multiple 
   // test cases
    dom = fixture.nativeElement;
    button = dom.querySelector('#btnMenu');
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

 it('should update the customer number on selecting a value from drop down', () => {
    // initially no mat-menu is opened
    let menu = dom.parentNode.querySelector('.mat-menu-panel');
    expect(menu).toBeFalsy();

    // trigger the menu
    button.click();

    // mat menu should be open now
    menu = dom.parentNode.querySelector('.mat-menu-panel');
    expect(menu).toBeTruthy();

    // click on the first element of the menu,it should pass the 0 index to the 
    // onCustomerChange method
    dom.parentNode.querySelector('#btn_0').click();
    expect(component.customerNumber).toBe(component.customers[0].ownerid);
  });
```

You can implement this as 3 different test cases as well.
Hope you've got the idea.!

Enjoy!!